# Char array in for loop: Palindrome program

Tags: arrays, for-loop, char

I cannot get the following code to run but I am unsure why. I am attempting to write the following code in order to output whether or not a char array is a palindrome. Thanks

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        boolean palindrome = false;

        char[] c = { 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a' };

        int n = c.length;

        for (int i = 0; i < (c / 2) + 1; i++) {

            if (c[i] != (n - c - 1)) {
                palindrome = false;
            }
        }

        palindrome = true;

        System.out.println(palindrome);

    }// main end

}// class end
```

Comment: Are you seeing an error message? If so, please post it. Thanks!

Comment: more information other than I cannot get it to run would help.  Any errors?

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < (c / 2) + 1; i++) {` Should `(c / 2)` be `(n / 2)`?

Comment: you may want (n/2) instead of c/2. and n-c-1 should be c[n-i-1]???

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 The operator / is undefined for the argument type(s) char[], int
 The operator - is undefined for the argument type(s) int, char[]

 at uk.ac.qub.typesdemo.Microsoft.main(Microsoft.java:15)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Palindrome {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        testPalindrome();
    }

    public static boolean isPalindrome(String str) {
        char[] c = str.toCharArray();
        int n = c.length - 1;
        int i = 0;
        while (i < n) {
            if (c[i] != c[n]) {
                return false;
            }
            i++;
            n--;
        }
        return true;
    }

    // This method tests the isPalindrome method
    // if any test fails a message will be printed and the program terminated
    public static void testPalindrome() {
        assertTrue(isPalindrome("abba"), 
                "Failed asserting 'abba' is a Palindrome");
        assertTrue(isPalindrome("abcba"), 
                "Failed asserting 'abcba' is a Palindrome");
        assertTrue(isPalindrome("aaaa"), 
                "Failed asserting 'aaaa' is a Palindrome");
        assertTrue(isPalindrome("#171#"), 
                "Failed asserting '#171#' is a Palindrome");
        assertTrue(isPalindrome("AbccbA"), 
                "Failed asserting 'AbccbA' is a Palindrome");
        assertTrue(isPalindrome("AAaAA"), 
                "Failed asserting 'AAaAA' is a Palindrome");

        assertTrue(! isPalindrome("abcbab"), 
                "Failed asserting 'abcbab' is NOT a Palindrome");
        assertTrue(!isPalindrome("Abccba"), 
                "Failed asserting 'Abccba' is NOT a Palindrome");
        assertTrue(!isPalindrome("Theses are tests"), 
                "Failed asserting 'Theses are tests' is NOT a Palindrome");
        assertTrue(!isPalindrome("AAAa"), 
                "Failed asserting 'AAAa' is NOT a Palindrome");
        assertTrue(!isPalindrome("AAAav"), 
                "Failed asserting 'AAAav' is NOT a Palindrome");
        assertTrue(!isPalindrome("12345678909876543210"), 
                "Failed asserting '12345678909876543210' is NOT a Palindrome");
    }

    public static void assertTrue(boolean test, String failMsg) {
        if (!test) {
            System.out.println(failMsg);
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Can u give me any advise on how i would test the pervious function?

Comment: do you mean the main method in your question?

Comment: yes I think so, or testing the method to ensure it is working as hoped

Comment: please see testPalindrome method and assertTrue method

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing a character with an undefined expression in your if statement. `c[i]` is a character ('a' or 'b'  in this example), but `n - c - 1` is not defined, as you can't subtract a character array (`c`) from an integer (`n`).

You are also trying to divide a character by 2, which is undefined in your for statement. It should be `i < (n/2)` instead.

Comment: I now have the following code which runs but always gives the output of false?

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {

  boolean palindrome = false;

  char[] c = { 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a' };

  int n = c.length;

  for (int i = 0; i < (n / 2) + 1; i++) {

   if (c[i] != (n - i - 1)) {
    
    palindrome = false;
   
   }else { palindrome = true;
  
   }

  System.out.println(palindrome);

  }
  
 }

}// class end

Comment: You're still comparing c[i] (a character) with n-i-1 (an integer). The reason this doesn't cause a compiler error is that characters are technically integers associated with an encoding scheme. Try instead `if (c[i] != c[n-i-1])

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
for (int i = 0; i < (c / 2) + 1; i++)
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < (c / 2); i++
```

And then change

```
if (c[i] != (n - c - 1)) {
```

to

```
if (c[i] != c[n-i-1]) {
```

With your example that'll check:

```
c[0] == c[4-0-1] // i is 0, so c[0] == c[3], increment i to 1
c[1] == c[4-1-1] // i is 1, so c[0] == c[2], increment i to 2
//exit the loop as i (2) is not less than (4/2)
```

And it'll work with odd numbers of characters as well.